# Google CLI does not create Transfer Service and shows no detailed error

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface, documentation, gcloud, bq

I'm very new to Google Cloud CLI, sorry for the dumb question but it's really annoying.

I'm trying to execute this command:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --target_dataset=ds_scrummate --display_name='map_email' --data_source=amazon_s3 --params='{"data_path_template":"s3://sm-bigquery/map_email/{run_date}/*.csv", "destination_table_name_template":"ing_map_email", "file_format":"CSV", "max_bad_records":"0", "ignore_unknown_values":"true", "field_delimiter":",", "skip_leading_rows":"1", "allow_quoted_newlines":"true", "allow_jagged_rows":"false", "delete_source_files":"true"}'
```

I always get this error message back:

```
BigQuery error in mk operation: Parameters should be specified in JSON format
when creating the transfer configuration.
```

The JSON file above seems to be valid (I've tested it with online validator).
I've also tried the multiline version of this command with the same result.

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting JSON error here, despite of the validated content?
- How could I get a more detailed error? Is there a verbose flag for this command which I couldn't find?
- Why isn't there any good documentation which describes this type of error in detail?

Sources I've used:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer#bq https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool

Comment: I tried to run the same command that you pasted, but I didn't receive the same error as yours (at least the `--params=` is valid) . I suspect if there was something wrong with your CLI environment, or you have some invisible special character in your JSON. If I were you, I'd start `--params=` simple by having only one parameter inside to see when it becomes invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting JSON error here, despite of
> the validated content?

The online parsers do give valid json structure, but it could be that  the prompt is not recognizing `{run_date}` as a string, I think it is trying to parse it also. Or maybe the comma in `"field_delimiter":","` should be scaped.

> How: could I get a more detailed error? Is there a verbose flag for
> this command which I couldn't find?

`--apilog <filename>` outputs debug logs to a file.

> Why isn't there any good documentation which describes this type of
> error in detail?

If my suspicion is correct, I think the error message points to the right direction, we need to verify what's going wrong in the json; the debug logs might contain more specific details on the section that was not parseable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the error message from the CloudSDK is not very helpful. I had the same message ("Parameters should be specified in JSON format") trying to create a scheduled query in Powershell.

To find the error, I  modified "bq\bigquery_client.py" to output the Exception caused by `json.loads(params)`. The real error was "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes". This helped me to find the solution: I had to put the property names and values inside the params in double double quotes, for example: `--params='{ ""query"": ""test"" }'`